# How to install recommended packages

Tags: apt, software-installation, dependencies

On Ubuntu 14.04

```
$ dpkg --get-selections  | grep ^aspell
$ apt-cache depends aspell
aspell
  Depends: libaspell15
  Depends: libc6
  Depends: libncursesw5
  Depends: libstdc++6
  Depends: libtinfo5
  Depends: dictionaries-common
  Suggests: aspell-doc
  Suggests: spellutils
 |Recommends: aspell-en
 |Recommends: <aspell-dictionary>
    aspell-ca
    aspell-am
    aspell-ar
    aspell-ar-large
    aspell-bg
    aspell-br
    aspell-cs
    aspell-cy
    aspell-de
    aspell-de-alt
    aspell-el
    aspell-en
    aspell-eo
    aspell-eo-cx7
    aspell-es
    aspell-et
    aspell-eu-es
    aspell-fa
    aspell-fo
    aspell-fr
    aspell-ga
    aspell-gl-minimos
    aspell-he
    aspell-hr
    aspell-hsb
    aspell-hu
    aspell-hy
    aspell-id
    aspell-is
    aspell-it
    aspell-kk
    aspell-ku
    aspell-lt
    aspell-lv
    aspell-nl
    aspell-pl
    aspell-pt-br
    aspell-pt-pt
    aspell-ro
    aspell-ru
    aspell-sk
    aspell-sl
    aspell-sv
    aspell-tl
    aspell-uk
    aspell-uz
  Recommends: <aspell6a-dictionary>
    aspell-da
    aspell-no
  Breaks: <aspell-bin>
  Breaks: <aspell-bin:i386>
  Replaces: <aspell-bin>
  Replaces: <aspell-bin:i386>
  Replaces: aspell-hi
  Replaces: <aspell-hi:i386>
  Replaces: aspell-mr
  Replaces: <aspell-mr:i386>
  Conflicts: aspell:i386
```

Then

```
apt-get install --install-recommends aspell
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  aspell-en
Suggested packages:
  aspell-doc spellutils
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  aspell aspell-en
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 13 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/346 kB of archives.
After this operation, 711 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Why is it not installing the recommended packages, like `aspell-ca`? What do I need to do to install these?

Comment: You may find this useful: https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html

Comment: @Serg, I already know what recommends means. I just don't know how to install recommended packages.

Comment: did you try `sudo apt-get install --install-recommends packagename` is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @JoKeR, that is what I tried...it's in my question.

Comment: ah I can see it now but it does install extra packages isn't it?

Comment: if you want also suggested packages you can run `sudo apt-get install --install-suggests`

Comment: @JoKeR You're right that it does install the `aspell-en` recommendation - i think OP is asking why the other `aspell-*` packages aren't being installed (see my answer)

Comment: I suspect it's an interpreting output problem. I don't think aspell would actually recommend ALL dictionaries. I do think it would say "I know you want at least one dictionary, so I'm going to recommend a category of package aspell-dict. I'm not going to actually recommend EVERY package in that category, but I'll try to help you choose one."

Comment: @hbdgaf that's still the case - but it expands to go into "If they really want the dictionaries, then install them yourself."  The key point is above the horizontal rule, though, in that they've misinterpreted the output.  Going above and beyond never hurts :)

Comment: @PaulDraper You could also have your install line like:  `sudo apt-get install --install-recommends aspell aspell-*` which would grab all the extra dictionary entries and install them as well.

Answer (score 5):

You've misinterpreted the output from the command.

It already gave you the recommended package for installation based on your language settings and the most likely package in the *category* of packages you're seeing in the "Recommends:" lines, `aspell-en`, which is the English dictionaries.  The system very likely isn't going to install ***all*** the dictionaries for ***all*** the different languages that `aspell` supports (which wouldn't make sense anyways, since you probably won't use them).

---

***However...***

If you want **some** of the other languages supported, you will probably have to install them individually, such as if you wanted `en` (English) and `es` (Spanish) then: `sudo apt-get install aspell-en aspell-es`  (this will install `aspell-en` if it's not installed, and also install the Spanish dictionaries in `aspell-es`)

If you want **all** the others, you may have to install them all with one massive command like this (Note that this command as it currently stands ***is not tested*** and may trigger conflicts. I'm also not sure why you'd want all the dictionaries for all the different languages, since it's insane to want to be installing all of the languages you *aren't* going to use):

```
sudo apt-get install aspell-ca \
    aspell-am \
    aspell-ar \
    aspell-ar-large \
    aspell-bg \
    aspell-br \
    aspell-cs \
    aspell-cy \
    aspell-de \
    aspell-de-alt \
    aspell-el \
    aspell-en \
    aspell-eo \
    aspell-eo-cx7 \
    aspell-es \
    aspell-et \
    aspell-eu-es \
    aspell-fa \
    aspell-fo \
    aspell-fr \
    aspell-ga \
    aspell-gl-minimos \
    aspell-he \
    aspell-hr \
    aspell-hsb \
    aspell-hu \
    aspell-hy \
    aspell-id \
    aspell-is \
    aspell-it \
    aspell-kk \
    aspell-ku \
    aspell-lt \
    aspell-lv \
    aspell-nl \ 
    aspell-pl \
    aspell-pt-br \
    aspell-pt-pt \
    aspell-ro \
    aspell-ru \
    aspell-sk \
    aspell-sl \
    aspell-sv \
    aspell-tl \
    aspell-uk \
    aspell-uz \
    aspell-da \
    aspell-no
```

Comment: I was just going to answer that, and you beat me to it!  :)  +1

Comment: @Terrance My speedy fingers are fast.  :)

Comment: Indeed they are!  :D

Comment: good one +1 ;) ...

Comment: I don't disagree, but I was talking to someone about the question in chat and arrived at: ~"Uptick from me. I wouldn't accept that answer if I were the OP though. I would want someone to point at where in the packaging process you can recommend a category containing packages and let it choose."

Comment: FYI, I am creating a web service that includes spellchecking functionality. I would like to support as many languages as possible.

Comment: @PaulDraper I didn't say you couldn't however you should consider your target language first, make that work, then make others work to iron out internationalization issues...